Is it possible and how if so, to convert $\int_0^{\beta} t^{a+ibc} dt$ into $g(a,b,c,\beta)\int_{\phi(0)}^{\phi(\beta)} x^{a-ib} dx$?
How to do so, if possible:
$$\displaystyle \int_0^{\beta} t^{a+ibc} dt = \displaystyle g(a,b,c,\beta)\int_{\phi(0)}^{\phi(\beta)} x^{a-ib} dx ~~~~~?$$
$\beta, a, b, c$ being non null real numbers, $i$ being the imaginary unit, $\phi$ being a function to find, to make a variable change if it is possible, $g$ being a real or complex function that could appear.
It may seem inappropriate to immediately use a complex variable change like "$t=\phi(z)$", where $z$ would be a complex number, that may end in obtaining complex integral limits, although I read that it has already been used in certain cases, cases that I haven't yet mastered at all. But would it be possible here?
I thought about making the variable change "$t=e^x$", obtaining then exponential function integrands, still with real limits, and then make a complex variable change, that would then make the values of the antiderivative defined?
I don't master complex integration, Cauchy's theorem, contour integrals... Would it be possible not to use these? I am not afraid to learn about it. I just want to make it in the most simple way, that could use complex integration theorems or anything else.
There may be much more simple and secure ways than what I suggested, ways that I don't see right now.
Thanks for any answer or comment!
